# Как реализовать просьбу оценить iOS - приложение в AppStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore

Как реализовать просьбу оценить iOS - приложение в AppStore? Например, я хочу попросить пользователя оценить приложение через N-ое количество запусков приложения.

Comment: вы даже не представляете сколько тысяч таких библиотек на гитхабе

Comment: Можно воспользоваться этими утилитками. В описании есть про получение ссылок. https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate

Answer (score 7):

На запуске приложения смотреть если ли в NSUserDefaults ключ, например "rate". если его нет, создать и присвоить = 0. Если уже есть и значение >= 0, то прибавить 1. Когда дойдет до 10 показать на экран алерт "зацени прилагу". если пользователь нажал хочу, то открывать аппстор (и присваивать каунтеру -1); если нажал позже, то обнулять каунтер; если нажал отвалите присваивать каунтеру -1 и больше пользователя не трогаете.

Касательно как знать линк в аппстор до того, как опубликовали приложение: когда вы создали новое приложение в itunesconnect он вам сразу даст линк, где оно будет храниться в аппсторе, этот линк вы используете, чтобы отправлять пользователей делать рейты.

Вы не можете знать что сделал пользователь в аппсторе и поставил ли он вам рейтинг. тут на доверии - если нажал открыть аппстор, то больше к нему не лезьте.

Не забудьте, что можно пользователя заново просить оценить после каждого апдейта. Для этого сохраняете еще одно значение в userDefaults - какую версию просили оценить. если видите, что версия поменялась, опять обнуляете каунтер.

Comment: Я так и предполагал, но сомневался правильный ли это путь. Хотел узнать как делают профессионалы. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А как получить ссылку для голосования за ios приложение до того как приложение будет опубликовано?

Comment: там в ответе есть - как только вы внесли информацию в itunesconnect, но до того как залили билд, вам доступна сыылка

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ был очень полезен для меня! Прошу прощения за невнимательность.