# переход в Appstore, а именно в раздел отзывов.

Tags: ios, swift

В моем приложении есть пункт оставить отзыв, пока что он кидает только в раздел "Подробнее" в Appstore, мне нужно в раздел "Отзывы".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать просьбу оценить iOS - приложение в AppStore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538075/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%b1%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-ios-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-appstore)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, нет, всё-таки не дубликат. Там речь о реализации оценки, а тут об адресе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте **url** типа: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id\(appID)?ls=1&mt=8&action=write-review`

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755069/how-can-i-add-a-link-for-a-rate-button-with-swift) можно посмотреть более подробно.

Comment: большое спасибо.